# Firestore in functions throws billing error about external traffic

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase function for creating thumbnails whenever an image is uploaded. It's working great!

I then decided I wanted to store the thumbnail URL in the proper document in a firestore collection. I went through the examples and I found the relevant code to access my firestore through the admin object

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// etc

return admin.firestore()
            .collection("my-collection")
            .doc(colId)
            .set({ thumbUrl: fileUrl });
```

But when I added this code the function started failing with this message:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
>   quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these
>   restrictions

My code

```
// before is the upload to bucket that works
.then(() => {
  fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);

  return Promise.all([
    tempFilePath.getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: "03-09-2491"
      })
    ]);
  })
  .then(results => {
    console.log("Got thumb signed URL");
    const thumbResult = results[0];
    const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];

    // Add the URLs to the Database
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("my-collection")
      .doc(colId)
      .set({ thumbUrl: thumbFileUrl });
  })
  .then(() => console.log("User was updated with thumb url"));
```

Well, I understand that the free plan only allows external access to Google's internal stuff but I'm using firestore... it's Google.

What could be wrong?

firebase-admin is at v5.4.2

firebase-functions is at v0.7.1

Comment: The message is just a warning and has no bearing on Firestore.  Please show the rest of your code, as there might be something else wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited my question

Comment: That doesn't look like the full code for a Cloud Function.  It's a fragment of code, so it's impossible to see how the whole thing works here.

Comment: @DougStevenson because the rest is nothing but uploading to the bucket. Doesn't invoke any other services but ImageMagick like in the docs example. So I only added the relevant code

Comment: It's up to you.

Comment: You said it invokes ImageMagick. That's an external tool.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes ImageMagick runs in Google's servers. It isn't an external access. External accesses can be using Sengrid for sending emails for example. Some foreign API

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the free Spark plan these messages will appear even if you are not trying to do any external access.